# Parsing blocks of text data with python itertools.groupby

Tags: python, python-itertools, text-parsing

I'm trying to parse a blocks of text in python 2.7 using itertools.groupby
The data has the following structure:

```
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=cmpd01_scan=23
RTINSECONDS=14.605
PEPMASS=694.299987792969 505975.375
CHARGE=2+
615.839727 1760.3752441406
628.788226 2857.6264648438
922.4323436 2458.0959472656
940.4432533 9105.5
END IONS
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=cmpd01_scan=24
RTINSECONDS=25.737
PEPMASS=694.299987792969 505975.375
CHARGE=2+
575.7636234 1891.1656494141
590.3553938 2133.4477539063
615.8339562 2433.4252929688
615.9032114 1784.0628662109
END IONS
```

I need to extract information from the line beigining with "TITLE=", "PEPMASS=","CHARGE=".

The code I'm using as follows:

```
import itertools
import re

data_file='Test.mgf'
def isa_group_separator(line):
    return line=='END IONS\n'

regex_scan = re.compile(r'TITLE=')
regex_precmass=re.compile(r'PEPMASS=')
regex_charge=re.compile(r'CHARGE=')


with open(data_file) as f:
    for (key,group) in itertools.groupby(f,isa_group_separator):
        #print(key,list(group)) 
        if not key:
            precmass_match = filter(regex_precmass.search,group)
            print precmass_match            

            scan_match= filter(regex_scan.search,group)
            print scan_match

            charge_match = filter(regex_charge.search,group)
            print charge_match
```

However, the output only picks up the "PEPMASS=" line,and if 'scan_match' assignment is done before 'precmass_match', the "TITLE=" line is printed only;

```
> ['PEPMASS=694.299987792969 505975.375\n'] [] []
> ['PEPMASS=694.299987792969 505975.375\n'] [] []
```

can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that `group` is an iterator and it runs only once.
Please find the modified script that does the job.

```py
import itertools
import re

data_file='Test.mgf'


def isa_group_separator(line):
    return line == 'END IONS\n'


regex_scan = re.compile(r'TITLE=')
regex_precmass = re.compile(r'PEPMASS=')
regex_charge = re.compile(r'CHARGE=')


with open(data_file) as f:
    for (key, group) in itertools.groupby(f, isa_group_separator):
        if not key:
            g = list(group)

            precmass_match = filter(regex_precmass.search, g)
            print precmass_match

            scan_match = filter(regex_scan.search, g)
            print scan_match

            charge_match = filter(regex_charge.search, g)
            print charge_match
```

Comment: Thanks. I guessed something same and tried to make a copy of the group using copy.copy() which didn't work too for the (now) obvious reeason. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I might try to parse this way (without using groupby(

```
import re

file = """\
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=cmpd01_scan=23
RTINSECONDS=14.605
PEPMASS=694.299987792969 505975.375
CHARGE=2+
615.839727 1760.3752441406
628.788226 2857.6264648438
922.4323436 2458.0959472656
940.4432533 9105.5
END IONS
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=cmpd01_scan=24
RTINSECONDS=25.737
PEPMASS=694.299987792969 505975.375
CHARGE=2+
575.7636234 1891.1656494141
590.3553938 2133.4477539063
615.8339562 2433.4252929688
615.9032114 1784.0628662109
END IONS""".splitlines()

pat = re.compile(r'(TITLE|PEPMASS|CHARGE)=(.+)')
data = []

for line in file:
    m = pat.match(line)
    if m is not None:
        if m.group(1) == 'TITLE':
            data.append([])
        data[-1].append(m.group(2))

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[['cmpd01_scan=23', '694.299987792969 505975.375', '2+'], ['cmpd01_scan=24', '694.299987792969 505975.375', '2+']]
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution